# Button android while pressed

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to print something while my button is pressed (not after it is released).
At moment I have this, but it only works once...

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to continually be printing "pressed" to the console? Or do you want it to only show once?

Comment: so do you want to print the "pressed" message as long as your button is pressed ?

Comment: yes,both questions above

Comment: Start a thread on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN which will print message and stop that thread on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.out doesn't work in an Android Device (won't show you anything on the device)
and if you have a text view you can set the text on your `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` as you are already doing and on the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you set your text of your text view to empty.
Something like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    textView.setText("Button Pressed");
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    textView.setText(""); //finger was lifted
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.out` data can be viewed in LogCat.

Comment: but yet would be useless on the device

Comment: the correct way to display messages on the LogCat is using the Log method... ie.  Log.e("myClass", "MyMessage");

Answer (score 4):

try this to continously print pressed message while you are pressing it.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
            return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, absolutely perfect!